# Matlab MCR expired

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I have the Matlab Compiler Runtime installed on my machine. It was working fine, but now when I run some code that needs it I get this error:

> Failed to initialize MCR Instance: The specified component has expired.

I thought the MCR was basically a free download but now I'm wondering if I had a trial version or something, even though as far as I can see there's nothing that says this is the case on the Matlab download site.

Anybody else had the same problem?

Comment: Is this a Java question?

Comment: I don't know if it's specifically Java- I'm using classes generated by Matlab's Java Builder but I'm not sure that's the issue. Maybe I shouldn't have tagged as Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the executable can expire, but not the MCR. Say a colleague of yours had trial license of MATLAB Compiler and he compiled an executable. He went onto distribute the executable to you. This executable would work only for 1 month. Past that, the executable expires.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm not clear on the relationship between the compiler and Java Builder, which is licensed. I'd have thought that would include a licensed compiler but maybe not. EDIT looks like the compiler is the issue. Thanks Lokesh

Comment: +1 what about executables produced using a full version of MATLAB Compiler (with a network license), is it tied to the lifetime of the MATLAB license (say if the license expires and is not renewed)?

Comment: That will work. The executable then has not lifetime defined as such.